# Remove Category title from WooCommerce Shop Page

Tags: themes

After the last update of my theme (Ashe Pro) the name of the product category has suddenly been added to the top of my product pages. I don't want this as I have a product menu in my sidebar. I've added a CSS code that I found online to remove this title, and it works. The only problem is it also removes the top of my sorting box, and it doesn't look good. Anyone who knows what to do to remove the title but let the sorting box remain as it was?